# Como extraigo una variable de una funcion para colocarla en otra funcion

Tags: javascript

Nesecito que la "x" tambien sea parte del entorno de "mostrar" pero sin declarar la variable global

```
function mostrar() {
  function add(n){
    x = words.concat(n)
    console.log(x) 
    box.innerHTML = words.concat(n);
    return x;
  }
  console.log(x)   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso es fácil, porque ya haces un `return` del valor de la variable `x` dentro de la función, y tan solo debes asignar a una nueva variable la ejecución de la función, fuera de la función:

```js
words = "hola "
function mostrar() {
  function add(n) {
    x = words.concat(n)
    console.log(x)
    box.innerHTML = words.concat(n);
    return x;
  }
  y = add("LouisSarmiendo")
  console.log(y)
}
mostrar()
```

```html
<div id="box"></id>
```

También tienes otra forma, sin usar variables globales, que es usando **variables locales** con [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), sin necesidad de usar el `return`.  Definiéndolas de esta forma su alcance es **local**, dentro de la función `mostrar()` en este caso, y para todo lo que la contenga, como puedes ver en este ejemplo:

```js
words = "hola "
function mostrar() {
  let x
  function add(n) {
    x = words.concat(n)
    console.log(x)
    box.innerHTML = words.concat(n);
  }
  add("LouisSarmiendo")
  console.log(x)
}
mostrar()
```

```html
<div id="box"></id>
```

Y si lo que pretendes es conseguir ese dato fuera del ámbito de la función completamente, podrias hacer lo siguiente tambien, mediante un `return` de la variable local `x` definida antes y utilizada internamente dentro de la primera función `mostrar()`:

```js
let words = "hola "
function mostrar() {
  let x
  function add(n) {
    x = words.concat(n)
    console.log(x)
    box.innerHTML = words.concat(n);
  }
  add("LouisSarmiendo")
  console.log(x)
  return x
}
let y = mostrar()
console.log(y)
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Como ves, tienes distintas formas de conseguirlo, y debes utilizar la que más te convenga en cada caso, según lo que pretendas lograr realmente.